# How to get the last activity timestamp performed by all users from Slack from API

Tags: api, slack, slack-api

I am trying to get details on last activity timestamp for all the users present in slack.
there is one end point [`team.accessLogs`](https://api.slack.com/methods/team.accessLogs) this gives you out the current team's last activity where as I am looking out for users from complete workspace.

Tried with `team.accessLogs` but it just give me team's access logs

Comment: What exactly is your issue with `team.accessLogs`? It should give you exactly the info you are asking for. What are you missing? Are you getting errors? Please add you current best code to the question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Erik. Team.AccessLogs works for me but just gives me out information of 3 4 users (my team members) even documentation says https://api.slack.com/methods/team.accessLogs 'Gets the access logs for the current team.'. I need same information for all the users from my workspace.

Comment: "team" and "workspace" is the same on Slack. If you are missing users in the logs, have you checked if they are additional pages? Those logs should be complete